# Google adsense and dynamic pages

Tags: advertising, google-adsense

I want to show Adsense in search results that come from my database.

How could google adsense bot determine what ads to show? Does it do so on the flow, i mean, there is no previous page it can visit to determine keywords if the results are dynamic.

What should i do in order Adsense shows relevant ads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Google](http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=20763) you will need to modify how that page works for Adsense to properly handle them:

> Our AdSense crawlers index each individual URL containing the AdSense
>   ad code in order to deliver relevant ads to that page. If your site is
>   dynamically generated using a program language such as PHP or is
>   created using information from a database, we'll still be able to
>   target each unique URL with ads specific to the content of that page.
>
> However, the following types of dynamic sites may need modification to
>   receive targeted ads:
>
> Dynamic pages that use the POST method for form submission Sites using
>   the POST method use the same URL for many different content pages. To
>   allow us to target the content of each unique page, we recommend that
>   you change these pages so that your variables are passed through the
>   URL using the GET method.

I'm guessing they will use the keywords in the query string to help them determine what ads to show and/or once the page is loaded for the first time they will know to crawl it with those parameters in the query string which will show them the content of that page which will allow them to server relevant ads going forward.

Comment: Thanks again. Since you like to give advise, the website i'm al the time referring to is www.buscatiendas.com.mx (feel free to mail comments, email is in my profile).

Comment: The reason is that they will use that url to pull the data. Using post they wouldn't get to see the page my users get to see. So it's not about being unique or containing keywords. It's about google bot getting to see the exact same page which they can only if all the post parameters are in the url.